# No sound from I2S codec

Tags: stm32, audio, i2s

I have a STM32F411R Nucleo board and I'm trying to connect it to a CS4245 audio codec to play audio but I can't get any sound out of it.

The connections are:

| Nucleo | CS4245 |
| --- | --- |
| PB10 (I2S3 MCLK) | 40 (MCLK2) |
| PA4 (I2S3 LRCLK) | 39 (LRCLK2) |
| PB12 (I2S3 SCLK) | 38 (SCLK2) |
| PC12 (I2S3 SD) | 37 (SDIN) |

I tested them for a continuity with a multimeter in case I had a cold solder joint but the I2S lines appear to be properly connected to the chip.

I have the Nucleo configured on I2S3 for half-duplex master transmit, 16 bit data on a 16 bit frame (Phillips I2S mode) with a 22 kHz sample rate.

I have the CS4245 registers configured like so:

| Register | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3h | 10h | Single speed, I2S up to 24-bit format with DAC as slave |
| 6h | 21h | DAC output, ASYNC bit set |
| 2h | 0h | Clear the PDN bit |

I have the control port on I2C to free up the SPI interfaces for I2S. I can write and read back the correct value so I'm pretty sure they work.

I can verify there is data on the I2S lines with my logic analyzer and the frequencies look correct.
[image]

I think the AOUTA and AOUTB lines are correctly connected because I can hear a speaker pop when I reset the device but nothing when I play the sound. I'm using a pair of powered computer speakers to monitor the output.

Not sure what to do at this point. I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Did you write any of the I2C registers? For example the "Power Control" register seems quite relevant to write as it is in a power-down state at reset.

Comment: Yes, the power down bit is on register 2h which I set to 0.

Comment: Is the MCLK frequency compatible with the sample rate and bitclock? Does this have a volume control register? Status of RESET pin?

Comment: What is the MCLK speed?

Comment: Volume control registers Bh and Ch are both set to 0h which is max volume.  The RESET# pin is tied to PB14 and I have it set high when I initialize the Nucleo.

Comment: I'm not sure if MCLK and SCLK are jittery or if it's just my logic analyzer. If you look at the trace every once in a while it gives a long pulse.  MCLK seems to bounce between 5Mhz and 6.25Mhz and SCLK seems to bounce between 694 and 714Khz. SCLK should be 22,050 * 16 * 2 = 705.6 Khz and MCLK should be 22,050 * 256 = 5.644Mhz which is in the ballpark, I guess? Maybe there is a margin of error at those speeds?

Comment: It was my logic analyzer not getting a clear reading. I increased the resolution to 50MS/s and MCLK is 5.556Mhz and SCLK is 704.225Khz.

Comment: This has happened serval times when I am working with applications. Some advice I can give you is ensure the signals are correctly seen between the STM32 MCU and the Audio Codec (CS4245). Double check that the STM32 MCU is master and the codec is slave, check for the sampling frequency ratio for example SLCK/MCLK. FS/MCLK is accepted in the I2S ratio table between the STM32 I2S and the audio codec table(refer to STM32 reference sheet and data sheet for audio codec). If still not working ensure, SPI communication is correct and double check the volume register and if its not muted.  Good luck.